# CityEngine PyDev Console "Console already exited with value: 0 while waiting for an answer."

Tags: python, console, jython, pydev, esri

I receive an error or warning while trying to use CityEngine PyDev Console for first time.The error:
[image: The error]

And here is the log message that I can't find a solution about it.
The log message:
[image: The log message]

Comment: Log message suggests that you are trying to call the library posix but it can't find it.

Comment: It could be a part of scripting, sys or os but I cant find it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. The only reason for its not working is system language of Windows. We switched it to English from Turkish and now, it is working!

Answer (score 0):

On a regular Jython env it seems to work for me, but I can see from the console output that they do some customizations in the scripting console initialization -- it's also a bit weird that in the traceback it says that it's initializing the IronPython console when apparently the output seems to say that it's Jython, so, I guess CityEngine has some custom configuration there (which could be the issue here).

Comment: Yes but CityEngine doesn't provide a "Preferences" interface that enables to interfere with the configuration. We have asked the problem to Esri's technical team, but still waiting an acceptable solution.

Comment: Im not sure but, could it be conflicted with other Python interpreters in my system?